# Does btrfs sync "suffer" from same issues as btrfs snapshot?

Tags: filesystems, btrfs, snapshot, persistence

Targeting "roughly *okay* backups" of a running system that uses BTRFS as filessytem, I seek an answer regarding

Can option

- a) `btrfs filesystem sync <path>`(`sync(1)`) be used to force an "*okay*" filsystem state of "persisted on disk" data, similar to option
- b) [`btrfs subvolume snapshot`](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Manpage/btrfs-subvolume), which I assume to be the "correct way", yet seems not to be without issues?

The issue I fear with *option b)* is from [this thread](https://marc.info/?l=linux-btrfs&m=157437495010246&w=2) of the btrfs mailing list:

> Snapshot create has unbounded running time on 5.0 kernels.  The
> creation process has to flush dirty buffers to the filesystem to get a
> clean snapshot state.  Any process that is writing data while the
> flush is running gets its data included in the snapshot flush, so in
> the worst possible case, the snapshot flush never ends (unless you run
> out of disk space, or whatever was writing new data stops, whichever
> comes first).

In essence I wonder how the `option a)` is actually different here, in that it would not suffer from a heavy-writer program outrunning the efforts of btrfs to create a `sync`ed state?

Being new to `btrfs` it might also be an unfounded fear, and the cow nature of `btrfs` will have an "okay" persisted on disk state, if so a reference (that I must have missed) regarding those guarantees would also resolve the issue of this question.